# 502 bad gateway on backend servers (nginx upstream module)

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

Hi have an 502 bad gateway problem when upstream server connects to NGINX backend servers (nodes).

if I use NGINX on backend servers then I got 502 bad gateway, if I use apache web server then no errors. doesn't matter if I use IPs instead of domains example server 192.101.876.76:8081

**nginx.conf**

```
http {
upstream appserver {
  server backend1.example.com; # with NGINX web server gives an 502 bad gateway when connected, with apache works fine
  server backend2.example.com; # with NGINX web server gives an 502 bad gateway when connected, with apache works fine
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
  proxy_pass http://appserver;
  }
}
```

**If I use Apache web server on backend1.example.com and backend2.example.com then it works. But I would like to use nginx because its more reliable and faster than apache.

Why it don't work with NGINX backend server?

Comment: Show working apache config

Comment: its basic config for apache. I am thinking I got the got "502 bad gateway" because nginx is working as reverse proxy for apache on backend servers. checked log files on nginx and dont show nothing

Comment: of course I have NGINX on port 80 and apache on port 8080. so main server(upstream) is listening port 80 only. so when nginx calls port 8080 occurs the error.